# Can elements of a list be used for a graph node's properties?

Tags: python, neo4j

I am still new to using Neo4j and Python. I want to know if it's possible to use elements of a list as a graph node's properties in Python and Neo4j.

I tried to create a Recipe node but I get an error in the 'createNode' variable. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
# a list containing a list of recipes and their respective information 
recipeList = [['Mac and Cheese', 'Anytime', 'Macaroni', 'Terry'], ['Chicken Curry', 'Supper', 'Chicken', 'Anne']]

def print_recipes(self,aList):
    with self._driver.session() as session:
       recipes = session.write_transaction(self.createRecipeNodes,aList)
            print(recipes)


def createRecipeNodes(tx, aRecipeList):

    for allRecipes in aRecipeList:
        #for recipe in allRecipes:
        recipeName = allRecipes[0]
        serveTime = allRecipes[1]
        mainIngrediant = allRecipes[2]
        givenBy =  allRecipes[3]

        createNode = tx.run("CREATE (theNode:Recipe {recipeName = {recipeName}, serveTime = {serveTime}, mainIngrediant = {mainIngrediant}, givenBy = {givenBy}" ,recipeName=recipeName,serveTime=serveTime,mainIngrediant=mainIngrediant,givenBy=givenBy)
```

The error I get is this:

`neo4j.exceptions.CypherSyntaxError: Invalid input '=': expected whitespace, comment, ':' or '}' (line 1, column 36 (offset: 35)) "CREATE (theNode:Recipe {recipeName = {recipeName}, serveTime = {serveTime}, mainIngrediant = {mainIngrediant}, givenBy = {givenBy}`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the error? It's easier than making us guess.

Comment: Apologies, the error I get is this: 

neo4j.exceptions.CypherSyntaxError: Invalid input '=': expected whitespace, comment, ':' or '}' (line 1, column 36 (offset: 35))
"CREATE (theNode:Recipe {recipeName = {recipeName}, serveTime = {serveTime}, mainIngrediant = {mainIngrediant}, givenBy = {givenBy}"

Comment: Put that in the question, properly formatted.

Comment: Just to note, a better approach would be to create a list of maps, with each map containing keys for recipeName, serveTime, mainIngredient, and givenBy.

That way, instead of using a loop for each create, you can instead make a single call with the list of maps as a parameter, and in your query UNWIND the list and perform a single CREATE (which will execute per row, so it will apply to all elements of your list). See [these tips and tricks](http://jexp.de/blog/2017/03/5-tips-tricks-for-fast-batched-updates-of-graph-structures-with-neo4j-and-cypher/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Cypher queries do not use `=` for property assignment but `:`,

```
createNode = tx.run("CREATE (theNode:Recipe {recipeName: {recipeName}, serveTime: {serveTime}, mainIngrediant: {mainIngrediant}, givenBy: {givenBy}"
 ,recipeName=recipeName,serveTime=serveTime,mainIngrediant=mainIngrediant,givenBy=givenBy)
```